# Issue regarding LM5117 TINA-TI model

Tags: switching-regulator

I have been using the Synchronous Buck Converter LM5117 in its typical circuit as described in the datasheet but have not been able to simulate. I have tried the circuit in MicroCap12, LTspice and TINA; and it hasn't worked. The following image is the typical circuit that I'm trying to build: [image]

In MicroCap12 it gives me an error in the model code regarding T (0,0). When I delete the T(0,0) it works for a bit and right after it gives a singularity error.

After been unsuccessful with MicroCap12 I went with LTSpice. When trying to simulate, it gives an error message saying that the V3 (which is a variable in the code of the LM5117) is shorted. [image]

In the error log there is an r19 (another variable in the code) which two pins are shorted together and is ignoring it. [image]

I made another attempt on creating the schematic block from scratch but couldn't sync the schematic block with the LM5117 model. [image]

After been unsuccessful with LTSpice I used TINA. In this case I couldn't even simulate the schematic symbol for the LM5117 because it didn't sync with its LM5117 model code.

In all of three cases I was using this LM5117 TINA-TI model:

```
    *$
*  LM5117
****************************************************************************
*  (C) Copyright 2014 Texas Instruments Incorporated. All rights reserved.
****************************************************************************
** This model is designed as an aid for customers of Texas Instruments.
** TI and its licensors and suppliers make no warranties, either expressed
** or implied, with respect to this model, including the warranties of 
** merchantability or fitness for a particular purpose.  The model is
** provided solely on an "as is" basis.  The entire risk as to its quality
** and performance is with the customer
****************************************************************************
*
** Released by: WEBENCH Design Center, Texas Instruments Inc.
* Part: LM5117  
* Date: 15SEP2014
* Model Type: TRANSIENT
* Simulator: PSPICE
* Simulator Version: 16.2.0.p001
* EVM Order Number: LM5117 Evaluation Board
* EVM Users Guide: SNVA466B – May2011 – Revised April 2013
* Datasheet: SNVS698E – APRIL 2011 – REVISED MARCH 2013
*
* Model Version: Final 1.10
*
****************************************************************************
*
* Updates:
*
* Final 1.10
* Implemented the CM, VCCDIS and Hiccup current limit.
*
* Final 1.00
* Release to Customer.
*
****************************************************************************
.SUBCKT LM5117_TRANS HB COMP CS CSG DEMB FB AGND HO LO PGND RAMP RT_SYNC SS 
+ SW VCC UVLO VIN RES VCCDIS EP CM
VRRTT RT RT_SYNC 
X_CL Ilim_1 GEN HICCUP ILIM RES HO LO VIN GND VRAMP SS HICCUP_SS 
+ FOR_CL_HIERARCHY 
X_VCC GND VCC VCCDIS VIN FOR_VCC
.MODEL _SCM_mod VSWITCH VON=0.5 VOFF=0.2 ROFF=100MEG RON=1u
ETRACK TRACK_1 AGND VALUE =  { -(V(CS,CSG)*20.87)+0.0184}
S_S1     N00045 TRACK_1 LO GND _SCM_mod 
R_R1         N00045 N00103  1 TC=0,0 
C_C1         GND N00103  0.2m  TC=0,0 
R_R2         GND CM  40k TC=0,0 
E_E1         CM 0 N00103 CM 20k
EB10 GEN GND Value {if(V(STANDBY) < 2.5 , 5 , 0)}
D3 13 0 _D3_mod
.MODEL _D3_mod D IS=1e-21 N=2.7
XA13 CLK_Din 3 INVERTERA13
XA13_Din_CLK CLK CLK_Din A2D
EB3 SS08 GND Value { if(V(SS)<V(Vref),V(ss),V(Vref)) }
IMY GND SS 10u
DMY GND SS_ref _D 
.MODEL _D D IS=1f RS=1m
VRefMY SS_ref GND 3
D5 0 13 _D5_mod
.MODEL _D5_mod D IS=1.0e-16 VJ=.31
V10 27 13
X21 VRamp_911 79 PWM COMPARX21
V911 Vramp_911 Vramp 0.1
R28 LO1 LO 2
EB8 9 GND Value {V(HO,SW)}
X5 SW 52 ZC COMPARX21
XA8 LOD 55_Din ZC_Din ZCLO_Dout NAND3A8
X_ASS 46_1 HICCUP_SS 46 OR2A
XA8_Din_55 55 55_Din A2D
XA8_Din_ZC ZC ZC_Din A2D
X_A8_Dout_ZCLO ZCLO_Dout ZCLO D2Ag
EBDembThresh 75 0 Value { if(V(SS) < 0.8 , 15 , 2.75)}
XVCO1  RT CLK CLK_GEN
S5 SS 0 46 GND _S5_mod
.MODEL _S5_mod VSWITCH VT=2.5 RON=.001 ROFF=1MEG
EB13 30 GND Value {V(ramp)}
VIlim 32 GND DC=1.2
XIlimComp VRamp 32 Ilim_1 ComparatorIlimComp 
R27 61 75 10 
S3 4 GUVLO HB SW _S3_mod
.MODEL _S3_mod VSWITCH VT=4.5 VH=0.25 ROFF=100MEG
V5 4 GND DC=5
R15 GUVLO GND 1Meg
XA10 28_Din 46_Dout INVERTERA13
XA10_Din_28 28 28_Din A2D
X_A10_Dout_46 46_Dout 46_1 D2Ag
C4 VRamp 30 100p
R7 ZCLOQ GND 100k
EBStandby STANDBY GND Value {if(V(UVLO) < 1.25 , 5 , if(V(VCC) < 4.5 ,
+ 5 ,0))}
EB2 HO1 SW VALUE={ if ((V(GEN) > 1) & (V(H) > 2.5) , V(HB,SW) , 0)}
EB6 LO PGND VALUE={if((V(GEN)>1) & (V(L) > 2.5) & (V(ZCLOQ) < 2.5) ,
+ V(VCC),0)}
C21 61 0 100p
.MODEL QPL PNP AF=1 BF=100 BR=1 CJE=0 CJC=0 CJS=0 EG=1.11 FC=0.5 
+ IS=1E-9 
+ MJC=0.33 MJE=0.33
+ ISC=0 ISE=0 ITF=0 KF=0 MJS=0 PTF=0 RB=0 RBM=0 RC=0 RE=0 TF=0 XTB=0 
+ XTF=0 
+ NC=2 NE=1.5 NF=1 NR=1 TNOM=27 VJC=0.75 VJE=0.75 VJS=0.75 XCJC=1 
+ XTI=3 NK=0.5
.MODEL _Q3_mod PNP AF=1 BF=100 BR=1 CJE=0 CJC=0 CJS=0 EG=1.11 
+ FC=0.5 IS=1E-9 
+ MJC=0.33 MJE=0.33
+ ISC=0 ISE=0 ITF=0 KF=0 MJS=0 PTF=0 RB=0 RBM=0 RC=0 RE=0 
+ TF=0 XTB=0 XTF=0 
+ NC=2 NE=1.5 NF=1 NR=1 TNOM=27 VJC=0.75 VJE=0.75 VJS=0.75 
+ XCJC=1 XTI=3 NK=0.5
EBramp 28 GND VALUE={ if(V(GEN) > 2.5 , 3 , 0)}
XA1  Rzzz QB  Q NOR2A
X3 61 DEMB 55 COMPARX5
EB1 62 GND Value {if(V(SS) > 3 , 5 , 0)}
STrack track VRamp CLK GND _TRACK
.MODEL _TRACK VSWITCH VT=2.5 RON=100m
S2 RAMP GND HOENB GND _S1_mod
.MODEL _S1_mod VSWITCH VT=2.5 RON=10m
GTrack GND track CSG CS {10*1e-3}
R14 track GND 1k
XA14 3 Q  HEN AND2A
R25 HO1 HO 2
XA3 57_Dout LOGIC0A3
X_A3_Dout_57 57_Dout 57 D2Ag
C6 HO SW 1p
XA16 PWM_Din Ilim_Din Rzzz OR2A
XA16_Din_PWM PWM PWM_Din A2D
XA16_Din_Ilim Ilim_1 Ilim_Din A2D
V3 GND 0
XA2 Q CLK_Din  QB NOR2A
D1 COMP 78 _D2_mod
.MODEL _D2_mod D N=1.09
V6 Vref GND DC=.8
X2 65 57 LEN ZCLO ZCLOQ ZQL DFLOPB
D2 78 79 _D2_mod
XA4 65_Dout LOGIC1A4
X_A4_Dout_65 65_Dout 65 D2Ag
XA5 62_Din SSLatch  69 NOR2A
XA5_Din_62 62 62_Din A2D
XA7 69 STANDBY_Din SSLatch NOR2A
XA7_Din_STANDBY STANDBY STANDBY_Din A2D
C2 LRC GND 10p
R26 LRC LO1 10k
R8 79 GND 100k
C7 LO PGND 1p
D4 LRC LO1 _D4_mod
.MODEL _D4_mod D RS=10
XA9 LRC_Din LOD BUFFERA9
XA9_Din_LRC LRC LRC_Din A2D
Rdemb DEMB 0 50k
XA17 9_Din HOENB_Dout INVERTERA13
XA17_Din_9 9 9_Din A2D
X_A17_Dout_HOENB HOENB_Dout HOENB D2Ag
VDembTrip 0 52 DC=.005
G2 0 27 SS08 FB 10m
R17 13 0 1MEG
C17 13 0 .53n IC=2
E1 COMP 0 13 0 1
R19 0 0 10
X7 LOF HOR DELAY PARAMS: TD=62n 
X8 LEN LEM DELAY  PARAMS: TD=150n 
X10 HOF LOR DELAY PARAMS: TD=55n 
XA18  HOR_Din HEN  H_Dout AND2A
XA18_Din_HOR HOR HOR_Din A2D
X_A18_Dout_H H_Dout H D2Ag
XA19 LEM_Din LEN_Din 73 AND2A
XA19_Din_LEM LEM LEM_Din A2D
XA20 LEN_Din LOR_Din 82 AND2A
XA20_Din_LEN LEN LEN_Din A2D
XA20_Din_LOR LOR LOR_Din A2D
XA21 HEN LEN_Dout INVERTERA13
X_A21_Dout_LEN LEN_Dout LEN D2Ag
XA22 73 82 L_Dout OR2A
X_A22_Dout_L L_Dout L D2Ag
EB7 HOF GND Value {if(V(SW) < 0.5*V(VCC) , 5 , 0)}
EB9 LOF GND Value {if(V(LO) < 0.25*V(VCC) , 5 , 0)}
R12 L GND 100k
R23 H GND 100k
.ENDS LM5117_TRANS
*$
.SUBCKT COMPARX21 NINV INV OUT
EB1 4 0 Value = {if(V(NINV,INV) > 0 , 5 , 0)}
RO 4 OUT 1m
CO OUT 0 1PF
.ENDS
*$
.SUBCKT ComparatorIlimComp NINV INV OUT 
EB2 HYS NINV Value {if( V(OUT) > 2.5, 50m , 0)}
EB1 4 0 Value { if(V(HYS,INV) > 0 , 5 , 0)}
RO 4 OUT 1m
CO OUT 0 1PF
.ENDS
*$
.SUBCKT COMPARX5 NINV INV OUT
EB1 4 0 Value {if(V(NINV,INV) > 0 , 5 , 0)}
RO 4 OUT 1
CO OUT 0 10n
.ENDS
*$
.SUBCKT DELAY 1 3 PARAMS: TD=62n
RIN 1 2 1E4
C1 2 0 {TD/(2.3*1E4)}
E1 3 0 2 0 1
.ENDS
*$
.SUBCKT D2Ag in out
XA1 in 1 D2A
R1 1 out 15
.ENDS
*$
.SUBCKT INVERTERA13 1 2 
EB1 3 0 VALUE {IF( V(1) > 1.5, 0.3, 3.5)}
R1 3 2 1
C1 2 0 10n IC=3.5000
.ENDS
*$
.SUBCKT A2D 1 2 
EBADC 2 0 Value { if(V(1,0) < 0.6 , 0.3 , if( V(1,0) >= 3 ,
+  3.5 , 1.5)) }
.ENDS
*$
.SUBCKT NAND3A8 1 2 3 4 
EB1 5 0  VALUE {IF(V(1) > 1.5 & V(2) > 1.5 & V(3) > 1.5, 
+ 0.3, 3.5)}
R1 5 4 100
C1 4 0 10P IC=3.5
.ENDS
*$
.SUBCKT D2A 1 2 
EBDAC 2 0 Value { if(V(1, 0) < 0.5 , 0.2 , if(V(1, 0) > 3.0 ,
+  3.5 , 1.8)) }
.ENDS
*$
.SUBCKT AND2A 1 2 4
EB1 5 0  VALUE {IF(V(1) > 1.5 & V(2) > 1.5, 3.5, 0.3)}
R1 5 4 1
C1 4 0 10n IC=0.0
.ENDS
*$
.SUBCKT OR2A 1 2 4
EB1 5 0  VALUE {IF(V(1) > 1.5 | V(2) > 1.5, 3.5, 0.3)}
R1 5 4 1
C1 4 0 10n IC=0.0
.ENDS
*$
.SUBCKT NOR2A 1 2 4
EB1 5 0  VALUE {IF(V(1) > 1.5 | V(2) > 1.5, 0.3, 3.5)}
R1 5 4 1
C1 4 0 10n IC=0.0
.ENDS
*$
.SUBCKT LOGIC0A3 1 
VPULLUP 1 0 0.3
.ENDS
*$
.SUBCKT LOGIC1A4 1 
VPULLUP 1 0 3.5
.ENDS
*$
.SUBCKT BUFFERA9 1 2 
EADC 3 0 1 0 1.0
R1 3 2 1
C1 2 0 10n 
.ENDS
*$
.SUBCKT Si7850DPM1 D G S
V1 D 4
V2 G 1
V3 S 2
M1 3 1 2 2 NMOS W=1611091u L=0.40u
M2 2 1 2 4 PMOS W=1611091u L=0.62u
R1 4 3 66E-4 TC=11.5E-3,5.5E-6
CGS 1 2 520E-12
DBD 2 4 DBD
.MODEL NMOS NMOS (LEVEL = 3 TOX = 7E-8
+ RS = 88E-4 RD = 0 NSUB = 1.44E17
+ KP = 2.1E-5 UO = 650
+ VMAX = 0 XJ = 5E-7 KAPPA = 7E-1
+ ETA = 1E-4 TPG = 1
+ IS = 0 LD = 0
+ CGSO = 0 CGDO = 0 CGBO = 0
+ NFS = 0.8E12 DELTA = 0.1)
.MODEL PMOS PMOS (LEVEL = 3 TOX = 7E-8
+NSUB = 2E16 TPG = -1)
.MODEL DBD D (CJO=500E-12 VJ=0.38 M=0.4
+RS=0.1 FC=0.5 IS=1E-12 TT=4.8E-8 N=1 BV=60.5)
.ENDS
*$
.SUBCKT D8_EXT A C
D5 A C _D8E_mod
.MODEL _D8E_mod D AF=1 CJO=2.667776e-11 EG=1.11 
+FC=0.5 IBV=10e-6 IS 2.843488e-9 KF=0 M=388.7e-3 N=1.091 
+RS=4.21e-1 TNOM=25 TT=0 VJ=632.1e-3 XTI=3 IBVL=0  
+ISR=0 NBV=1 NBVL=1 NR=2 TBV1=0 TBV2=0 TRS1=0 TRS2=0
*+CV=100 IKF=inf
.ENDS
*$
.SUBCKT DFLOPB 1 2 3 4 5 6
*CLRN D CLK PREN Q QN
X1 4 12 11 13 NAND3_0 
X2 13 1 3 11 NAND3_1 
X3 11 3 12 10 NAND3_0 
X4 10 1 2 12 NAND3_1 
X5 4 11 6 5 NAND3_0 
X6 5 1 10 6 NAND3_1
.ENDS
*$
.SUBCKT NAND3_0 1 2 3 4
EB2 6 0 4 0 100
EB1 5 0  VALUE {IF(V(1) > 1.5 & V(2) > 1.5 & V(3) > 1.5, 
+ 0.3, 3.5)}
R1 5 4 200
C1 4 0 20P IC=0
.ENDS
*$
.SUBCKT NAND3_1 1 2 3 4
EB2 6 0 4 0 100
EB1 5 0  VALUE {IF(V(1) > 1.5 & V(2) > 1.5 & V(3) > 1.5,
+  0.3, 3.5)}
R1 5 4 200
C1 4 0 20P IC=3.5
.ENDS
*$
.SUBCKT CLK_GEN RT CLK
IS1         0 RT 1U
XU6         4 3 RT VCR_0
XU5         4 3 D_D1_0
C2          3 0 1U 
XU2         5 4 INV_0
R5          6 0 1G 
XU4         6 5 RT VCR_1
XU3         5 3 CLK AND_0
XU1         7 6 5 COMPARATOR_0
C1          6 0 1U 
R2          0 7 1K 
R1          7 5 1K 
.ENDS
*$
.SUBCKT VCR_0  1 2 RT
G1 1 2 VALUE {(V(1,2)*3.604)*2/(250*V(RT)+237E-3)}
.ENDS
*$
.SUBCKT D_D1_0  1 2
D1 1 2 DD1
.MODEL DD1 D
+ IS=1E-011
+ TT=1E-09
+ RS=0
+ N=1.1
.ENDS D_D1_0 
*$
.SUBCKT INV_0  IN OUT
E1 OUT 0 VALUE {IF(V(IN)>0 , -12 , 12)}
.ENDS
*$
.SUBCKT VCR_1  1 2 RT
G1 1 2 VALUE {((V(1,2)*2*5.712*1E-3)/(V(RT)+948*1E-6))}
.ENDS
*$
.SUBCKT AND_0  1 2 OUT
E1 OUT 0 VALUE {IF(V(1)>0 & V(2)>0, 3.5 , 0.3)}
.ENDS   
*$
.SUBCKT COMPARATOR_0  P N Y
E1 Y 0 VALUE {IF(V(P,N)>0,12,-12)}
.ENDS
*$
.SUBCKT ONE_SHOT IN OUT PARAMS:T=100
S_S1         MEAS 0 RESET2 0 S1
E_ABM1         CH 0 VALUE { if( V(IN)>0.5 | V(OUT)>0.5,1,0)}
R_R2         RESET2 RESET  0.1  
E_ABM3         OUT 0 VALUE { if( V(MEAS)<0.5 & V(CH)>0.5,1,0)}
R_R1         MEAS CH  {T} 
C_C2         0 RESET2  1.4427n  
C_C1         0 MEAS  1.4427n  
E_ABM2         RESET 0 VALUE { if(V(CH)<0.5,1,0)    }
.MODEL         S1 VSWITCH Roff=1e9 Ron=1.0 Voff=0.25V Von=0.75V
.ENDS
*$
.SUBCKT srlatchrhp_basic_gen s r q qb PARAMS: vdd=1 vss=0 
+ vthresh=0.5 
gq 0 qint value = {if(v(r) > {vthresh},-5,if(v(s)>{vthresh},
+ 5, 0))}
cqint qint 0 1n
rqint qint 0 1000meg
d_d10 qint my5 d_d1
v1 my5 0 {vdd}
d_d11 myvss qint d_d1
v2 myvss 0 {vss} 
eq qqq 0 qint 0 1
x3 qqq qqqd1 buf_basic_gen PARAMS: vdd={vdd} vss={vss} 
+ vthresh={vthresh}
rqq qqqd1 q 1
eqb qbr 0 value = {if( v(q) > {vthresh}, {vss},{vdd})}
rqb qbr qb 1 
cdummy1 q 0 1n 
cdummy2 qb 0 1n
.ic v(qint) {vss}
.model d_d1 d
+ is=1e-015
+ tt=1e-011
+ rs=0.005
+ n=0.01
.ENDS
*$
.SUBCKT FOR_CL_HIERARCHY Ilim_1 GEN HICCUP ILIM RES 
+ HO LO VIN GND 
+ VRAMP SS HICCUP_SS  
R_R19         N163119542 N16311770  1  
C_C18         GND N16311718  1n  
C_C13         GND N16311374  1n  
R_R16         H_END_1 H_END  1  
R_R20         N16311794 N16311360  1  
E_ABM6         ILIM 0 VALUE { if(V(HICCUP)<0.5,V(N16311374),
+ V(HICCUP))}
C_C20         GND COUNTER  1u IC=0 
C_C17         GND H_END_1  20n  
R_R18         N16311658 HICCUP  1  
X_U612         GEN N16311360 N16311364 AND2_BASIC_GEN 
+ PARAMS: VDD=1 VSS=0
+  VTHRESH=500E-3
G_ABMII2         N16311806 COUNTER VALUE { if (V(N16311364) >
+ 0.5,1m,0) }
C_C15         GND N16311430  1n  
X_U632         RES N163119361 N16311566 COMP_BASIC_GEN 
+ PARAMS: VDD=1 VSS=0
+  VTHRESH=0.5
C_C19         GND N16311658  1n  
R_R12         ILIM_1 N16311374  1  
E_E1         HICCUP_SS GND HICCUP GND 5
X_U4         N16311566 H_END ONE_SHOT PARAMS:  T=50 
X_U613         N16311658 N16311636 INV_DELAY_BASIC_GEN 
+ PARAMS: VDD=1 VSS=0
+  VTHRESH=0.5 DELAY=10u
X_U616         N16311320 N16311718 N163119542 AND2_BASIC_GEN 
+ PARAMS: VDD=1
+  VSS=0 VTHRESH=500E-3
R_R14         HO N16311430  1  
E_ABM8         N16313522 0 VALUE { if(V(LO) >3.5,1,0)    }
X_U3         ILIM_1 N16311794 ONE_SHOT PARAMS:  T=200
X_U33         N16311690 H_END HICCUP HICCUP_N srlatchrhp_basic_gen 
+ PARAMS:
+  VDD=1 VSS=0 VTHRESH=0.5
X_S5    N16311482 GND COUNTER GND FOR_CL_S5 
C_C22         GND N16311360  1n  
V_V7         N163119361 GND 1.25
X_U615       COUNTER N16311762 N16311690 COMP_BASIC_GEN 
+ PARAMS: VDD=1 VSS=0
+  VTHRESH=0.5
R_R21         N16311314 N16311320  120  
R_R17         N16311442 N16311718  1  
C_C21         GND N16311770  1n  
C_C23         GND N16311320  1n  
V_V9         N16311806 GND 12
R_R15         ILIM N16311426  1  
C_C16         GND N16311426  1n  
X_U32       N16311430 N16311426 N16311442 QB_2 srlatchrhp_basic_gen 
+ PARAMS:
+  VDD=1 VSS=0 VTHRESH=0.5
E_ABM7         RESET 0 VALUE { IF(V(HO)<V(VIN),V(N16311770),0)    }
G_G5         GND RES HICCUP GND 10u
X_S6    H_END_1 GND RES GND FOR_CL_S6 
X_U649         N16313522 N16311314 d_d1
X_U650         N16311320 N16313522 d_d1
V_V8         N16311762 GND 51.2m
X_U614      N16311658 N16311636 N16311730 AND2_BASIC_GEN 
+ PARAMS: VDD=1 VSS=0
+  VTHRESH=500E-3
X_U648         RESET N16311730 N16311482 OR2_BASIC_GEN
.ENDS
*$
.subckt FOR_CL_S5 1 2 3 4  
S_S5         3 4 1 2 _S5
RS_S5         1 2 1G
.MODEL         _S5 VSWITCH Roff=1e6 Ron=1.0 Voff=0.25 Von=0.75
.ends FOR_CL_S5
*$
.subckt FOR_CL_S6 1 2 3 4  
S_S6         3 4 1 2 _S6
RS_S6         1 2 1G
.MODEL         _S6 VSWITCH Roff=1e9 Ron=1m Voff=0.25 Von=0.75
.ends FOR_CL_S6
*$
.SUBCKT FOR_VCC GND VCC VCCDIS VIN  
I_I3         GND N14931274 DC 2.5m  
X_D19         N14931274 N14931324 d_d1 PARAMS: 
R_R1         GND VCC  1000k TC=0,0 
C_C1         GND VCC  2u  
E_ABM1         N14931324 GND VALUE { if(V(VCCDIS)<1.25,7.6,0)    }
G_ABM2I2         VIN VCC VALUE { {LIMIT((V(N14931274) - 
+ V(VCC)-0.1)*10m,
+  -30m,30m)}    }
R_VCCIDS GND VCCDIS  1000k TC=0,0 
.ENDS
*$
.SUBCKT AND2_BASIC_GEN A B Y PARAMS: VDD=5 VSS=0 VTHRESH=2.5 
E_ABMGATE    YINT 0 VALUE {{IF(V(A) > {VTHRESH}  &  
+ V(B) > {VTHRESH},{VDD},{VSS})}}
RINT YINT Y 1
CINT Y 0 1n
.ENDS AND2_BASIC_GEN
*$
.SUBCKT COMP_BASIC_GEN INP INM Y PARAMS: VDD=5 VSS=0 VTHRESH=2.5    
E_ABM Yint 0 VALUE {IF (V(INP) > 
+ V(INM), {VDD},{VSS})}
R1 Yint Y 1
C1 Y 0 1n
.ENDS COMP_BASIC_GEN
*$
.SUBCKT INV_DELAY_BASIC_GEN A  Y PARAMS: VDD=5 VSS=0 
+ VTHRESH=2.5 DELAY = 10n
E_ABMGATE1    YINT1 0 VALUE {{IF(V(A) > {VTHRESH} , 
+ {VDD},{VSS})}}
RINT YINT1 YINT2 1
CINT YINT2 0 {DELAY*1.3}
E_ABMGATE2    YINT3 0 VALUE {{IF(V(YINT2) > {VTHRESH} , 
+ {VSS},{VDD})}}
RINT2 YINT3 Y 1
CINT2 Y 0 1n
.ENDS INV_DELAY_BASIC_GEN
*$
.SUBCKT BUF_BASIC_GEN A  Y PARAMS: VDD=5 VSS=0 VTHRESH=2.5 
E_ABMGATE    YINT 0 VALUE {{IF(V(A) > {VTHRESH} , 
+ {VDD},{VSS})}}
RINT YINT Y 1
CINT Y 0 1n
.ENDS BUF_BASIC_GEN
*$
.SUBCKT OR2_BASIC_GEN A B Y PARAMS: VDD=1 VSS=0 VTHRESH=0.5 
E_ABMGATE    YINT 0 VALUE {{IF(V(A) > {VTHRESH}  |  
+ V(B) > {VTHRESH},{VDD},{VSS})}}
RINT YINT Y 1
CINT Y 0 1n
.ENDS OR2_BASIC_GEN
*$
.SUBCKT D_D1 1 2
D1 1 2 DD1
.MODEL DD1 D( IS=1e-15 TT=10p Rs=0.05 N=.1 )
.ENDS D_D1
*$
.SUBCKT INV_BASIC_GEN A  Y PARAMS: VDD=1 VSS=0 VTHRESH=0.5 
E_ABMGATE    YINT 0 VALUE {{IF(V(A) > {VTHRESH} , 
+ {VSS},{VDD})}}
RINT YINT Y 1
CINT Y 0 1n
.ENDS INV_BASIC_GEN
*$
.SUBCKT LDCR IN OUT
+ PARAMs:  L=1u DCR=0.01 IC=0
L   IN 1  {L} IC={IC}
RDCR    1 OUT {DCR}
.ENDS LDCR
*$
```

I inserted 36V as the value for voltage source "V1" but have the same error of the V3 been shorted and about the R19 pins been shorted as well.
[image]

I downloaded PSpice for TI. Built the LM5117 Typical Circuit (The LM5117 is in the PSpice for TI library) as shown on previous photos. When simulation starts it doesn't provide the graph where the signals would be visible. After a few minutes it gives the following error:
[image]

This is the typical circuit that I built up in PSpice for TI.
[image]

Comment: V3 and R19 are not variables, they are circuit elements. You might want to read up on how SPICE works; you seem to be treating it as a programming language when it's really more like a hardware description language. "Variables" in SPICE (called parameters) never appear at the beginning of a line.

Comment: Remove the line `V3 GND 0`.  It shouldn't be there.  Also try fixing the 9 curly brace errors.  LTspice doesn't like nested curly braces.  They're also not required and poor syntax.  Whoever authored this library file relied on PSpice to ignore these problems.

Comment: I spent a couple hours trying to get this model to run.  Even though I solved all the syntax errors and warnings, this model is highly unstable.  I suggest trying to use either the TINA-TI reference design directly in TINA-TI or the PSpice encrypted model directly in PSPICE-FOR-TI.  This unencrypted PSpice model you're trying to use is not worth the trouble trying to get it to run in a 3rd party program like MicroCap or LTspice.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GR8w.png

Comment: @ste Kulov Trying to decide between TINA-TI and PSPICE-FOR-TI... which is better and when to use which?

Comment: @SteKulov Can you use Analog devices encrypted spice models in PSPICE-FOR-TI?

Comment: @nmr I'm not sure which is better.  I don't like either, personally.  I prefer LTspice for everything, but I've never been put into a situation where I was forced to use the others.  Encrypted models can only work in the program they were designed for.  LTspice encrypted models can only work in LTspice.  PSpice encrypted models can only work in PSpice.  And so forth...

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Apply a proper input first.

Your input supply, V1, has a voltage value of `V` which seems to be an undefined parameter in the simulator. This undefined parameter might be triggering further errors.

Put a number into V1's voltage field and re-run the simulation.